# Can I hardwire an LED retrofit disk

Tags: electrical, recessed-lighting

My contractor messed up and put junction boxes into my new house instead of using recessed cans like I was expecting. They were planning on using [something like these LED disks](https://www.superbrightleds.com/moreinfo/flush-mount-ceiling-light/5-12-flush-mount-led-ceiling-light-60-watt-equivalent-dimmable-led-disk-light-junction-box-mount-760-lumens/3274/). They wire directly to the power source instead of screwing into a can like I was expecting.

I bought [these Philip's Hue retrofit disks](https://www2.meethue.com/en-us/p/hue-white-ambiance-white-ambiance-5-6%E2%80%9D-retrofit-recessed-downlight/5995111U5) and I was planning on screwing them into the can, which I obviously can't do now.

My question is, can I use the hue disks and just snip the adapter wires and hard wire it? Or is there an adapter that just converts it to hard wire? They also have a 4" version instead if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those Philips disks you have are designed and tested to work inside a recessed can.  You cannot modify them as you are suggesting.  First, there's just no way to attach them to the junction boxes.  Second, it wouldn't be "legal" to electrical code and it may not be safe.

Your two options are to get a "flush mount" recessed light disk that is made to attach to a junction box or have the boxes replaced with proper recessed light cans.  Even the "flush mount" lights are 3/4" - 1" thick, so if you want a true recessed look, installing cans is your best option.